# Cakephp 3 update query isn't updating my database

Tags: cakephp, sql-update, cakephp-3.0

Okay, so I am using cakephp 3, the most recent version. This is how my query command looks like:

```
$team_sales
    ->query()
    ->update()
    ->set(['team_id' => $team_id])
    ->where(['id IN' => $ids])
    ->execute();
```

My `$team_id` is `8889664` and my `$ids` array looks like `[3, 8, 16, 24]`

I am getting back a success for this but when I check the database, the records haven't been updated. Any clue as to why?

Comment: Any reason why you are not using [**`Table::updateAll()`**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#bulk-updates)? Also how exactly are you checking the return value? Using [**`rowCount()`**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#getting-row-counts)? Because that's what you would have to do.

Comment: Hey ndm, I checked to see if updateAll would work and it doesn't. It still doesn't update any rows.

Comment: What's your peace of code with updateAll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out that this was correct the whole time. I should not have been using the id but rather another column. I appreciate all the help.